# How to see 'full' SQL Error Messages in BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am writing a large `MERGE` statement in BigQuery.

When I attempt to run this query the validator gives me an error involving a lot of `...`'s that hides the useful information as shown below:

```
Value has type ARRAY<STRUCT<eventName STRING, eventUUID STRING, eventDate DATE, ...>> which cannot be inserted into column Events, which has type ARRAY<STRUCT<eventName STRING, eventUUID STRING, eventDate DATE, ...>> at [535:1]
```

I am extremely confident these two array objects match exactly, however since I am struggling to get around this I would love to see the full error message.

Is there any way to see the full error?

I have looked into the Google Logging tool and cannot see any additional information.

I have also tried the following Cloud Shell command:

```
bq --format=prettyjson show -j [Job Id Goes Here]
```

Again, this seems to provide no additional information.

Comment: Can you check your [Loggings](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/monitoring) and filter by BigQuery ( in select resource) to see the error message there? Also you can check on Error [Reporting](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting). Although, the error message is just hiding the information because it probably has a couple of nested fields. The error itself can be interpreted as there are different columns or types in one of the fields you are trying to insert. You also could double check your query syntax. You can post your code and some dummy data so I can further help you.

Comment: I have managed to resolve the issue with my specific query (was an error deep in the arrays). However I am still curious about seeing larger error messages. The error string in Logging has the exact same issue and these type of errors don't show at all in error reporting as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

This approach feels pretty silly but it could be the last resort for really long nest type.

1. Use [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#columns_view) to get a full string of the target type, in your case, type of column `Events`.
2. Use `CREATE TABLE <yourDataset>.<yourTempTable> AS SELECT ...` to dump one row of the `Value` into a table. Use 1) again to see its full type string.